# Find the range of $m$ for which atleast one of the following equations $ax^2+bx+cm=0,bx^2+cx+am=0,cx^2+ax+bm=0$ have real roots.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Let $a,b,c$ and $m\in R^+$.Find the range of $m$ for which atleast one of the following equations $ax^2+bx+cm=0,bx^2+cx+am=0,cx^2+ax+bm=0$ have real roots.

---

Either one or two or all of the three equations $ax^2+bx+cm=0,bx^2+cx+am=0,cx^2+ax+bm=0$ have the real roots.
But i do not know how to find the range of $m.$Any help will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Use the quadratic formula on the first one.  Since the square-root is real, that gives you an inequality relating $a,b,c,m$.  Repeat.  Perhaps you can combine the three inequalities for a single one in terms of just $m$.

Comment: and you can suppose $a \ge b \ge c$

Comment: Just find the discriminant and put the condition that $D \ge 0$, where $D = b^2 - 4ac$ is the discriminant for $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Claim: $$m \leq \dfrac{1}{4}$$

For if all of them do not have real roots then : $a^2-4bcm < 0, b^2-4acm < 0, c^2-4abm < 0 \Rightarrow a^2+b^2+c^2 < 4m(ab+bc+ca) \Rightarrow m > \dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{4ab+4bc+4ca} \geq \dfrac{ab+bc+ca}{4ab+4bc+4ca} = \dfrac{1}{4}$. Thus if $m \leq \dfrac{1}{4}$, then at least one equation has real roots.

Comment: I think you proved no real roots implies $m\leq\frac14$.  You need to reverse the argument to get $m\geq\frac14$ implies yes at least one real root.

Comment: Not true. $m \leq \dfrac{1}{4} \Rightarrow $ at least one equation has real roots.

Answer (score 1):

At least one of the three discriminants has to be positive:

$b^2-4acm\geq0$

$c^2-4bam\geq0$

$a^2-4cbm\geq0$

Equivalently:

$\frac{b^2}{4ac}\geq m$

$\frac{a^2}{4ba}\geq m$

$\frac{c^2}{4bc}\geq m$.

One of these is true as long as $m$ is less or equal to the *maximum* of the three left hand sides.

So let $M=\max\{\frac{b^2}{4ac},\frac{a^2}{4ba},\frac{c^2}{4bc}\}$.

Since $m\geq0$ we must have $0\leq m\leq M$.

Comment: How will we find $M?$M need to be $\frac{1}{4}$.